# My app is Whitelisted by Twitter still not getting email of user some one help me?

Tags: twitter

I follow all these step : I have filled out the xAuth form by giving the details of my app in here https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform150 [I have added a youtube link for DEMO LINK and my app url in github for APPLICATION URL] and clicked on "submit" button.

Next,You will get 1st email from twitter(If you dont get an email from twitter,re-fill the form and send again) saying "Thanks for reaching out".Then after a few hours youll get a 2nd email saying that url app is whitelisted.

Once they say that your App is whitelisted, update your App's settings in Twitter Developer portal. Sign in to apps.twitter.com and:

On the 'Settings' tab, add a terms of service and privacy policy URL[which is must,try giving dummy url]
On the 'Permissions' tab, change your token's scope to request email. This option will only been seen, once your App gets whitelisted.

but still I am not getting mail.
please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The request needs to include the `include_email` parameter :

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true`

Also note that you MUST refresh your credentials on http://apps.twitter.com.
Failing to do so, Twitter will never return the email.

Comment: These things I have done but it is problem still I am getting email null.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with some users having email="".
We tested this and found that if a user doesn't verify their email address with twitter this is what the response will be. 
I would suggest testing logging in to your app with a twitter user who has definitely verified their email address.